# repository files explorer of Gitlab still displays the file which had been removed

Tags: git, gitlab

I'd run a local gitlab with local repositories.
The repository files explorer would still display the files which had been removed in head version.
Is there any configuration to fix it? I've looked around admin tools and cannot find that. 
Thanks,

Comment: The file still exists in the previous revisions. If you'd like to remove it from the whole history, search for `git filter-branch` and `git gc`.

Answer (score 0):

First, if you have removed the file locally, you still need to add, commit and push to GitLab in order to see that deletion.

Second, if you are talking about older commits still referencing that (now deleted) file, you have either [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch) or, easier, [bfg repo cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/).
Example: Delete all files named 'id_rsa' or 'id_dsa' (in the all repo history)

```
bfg --delete-files id_{dsa,rsa}  my-repo.git
```